# Faster way of sending mail using PHP and SMTP

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I send out mail via PHP using an virtual SMTP Server on a Windows 2008 Server.  The mail takes about 20 minutes to get delivered which seems crazy to me.  I am wondering if there is a quicker way to send mail via a php script?  The simpler the solution the better.

EDIT:
I setup a log for my SMTP server with the following results, still trying to figure out what it means and why the hangup so any help would be appreciated:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-10-17 18:36:48
#Fields: date time c-ip s-sitename s-ip s-port cs-method sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken 
2014-10-17 18:36:48 127.0.0.1 SMTPSVC1 127.0.0.1 0 HELO 0 57 38 0
2014-10-17 18:36:48 127.0.0.1 SMTPSVC1 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL 0 53 40 0
2014-10-17 18:36:48 127.0.0.1 SMTPSVC1 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT 0 48 45 0
2014-10-17 18:36:48 127.0.0.1 SMTPSVC1 127.0.0.1 0 DATA 0 146 2387 16
2014-10-17 18:36:48 127.0.0.1 SMTPSVC1 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT 16 82 4 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 - 0 71 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 EHLO 0 4 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 - 0 105 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 MAIL 0 4 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 - 0 44 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 RCPT 0 4 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 - 0 54 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 DATA 0 4 0 0
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 - 0 44 0 15
2014-10-17 18:57:46 x.x.x.x SMTPSVC1 - 25 - 0 29 0 125
```

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

I get a variety of errors right before and after the delay, seems different every time I run the script.  In my example you see

```
16 - "The directory cannot be removed"
```

I also get

```
15 - "The system cannot find the specified drive"
71 - This error apparently doesn't exist, but I get it
78 - This error apparently doesn't exist, but I get it
62 - Space to store the file waiting to be printed is not available on the server.
```

As well as some other error, not matter what the error it takes about 21 minutes each time between sending and receiving.  Another detail that may help, the 127.0.0.1 now read the IP of the Server which the IIS webserver resides on and the x.x.x.x is my smtp server.

Comment: Where is the bottleneck?  If the SMTP server receives the outgoing message immediately but internally takes a long time to send it, or if some other server along the path of that email is taking a long time, you can't fix that from your PHP code.

Comment: It seems that the SMTP server is the bottleneck.  When I receive the mail the "sent time" is when the script is run but the "received time" is about 20 minutes later.  I assume this means the PHP mail function is sending it to the SMPT server right away, but somewhere in the SMTP server it gets help up.

Comment: You should be able to tell where in the chain of connections it's being held up by looking at the 'received' headers. Things like greylisting and throttling can cause long delays like this. If you enable debug output (`SMTPDebug = 2`) you'll see exactly how long SMTP commands are taking.

Comment: as an addition note, when I send multiple emails it takes 20 minutes still but they all go through together even it I send 1 then wait 10 minutes and send another.

Comment: I have decided to abort this Virtual SMTP Server method of sending emails and use powershell.  Wish I would have done this sooner, so easy to get it working and sends my emails in seconds.